# Root of -1, multiple of 4 has to lie in first half?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, legendre-symbol

$n$ is an odd number, with a prime factorization containing only primes $\equiv 1 \mod 4$. $b$ is a root of $-1$ ($b^2 \equiv -1 \mod n$), $1<b<n$.

I have been unsuccessfully looking for a proof that when $b$ is a multiple of 4, then $b < \frac{n}{2}$.

Example: $n=17$, $b=4$. The other root of $-1$, namely $17-4=13$, is odd and lies in the second half of the interval $[1,n]$.

Other examples: $n=29, b=12$; $n=3277,b=1032$.

Who can help me with this proof?

Comment: Looks rather unlikely to me...

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown : unlikely maybe but then a counter example would be nice to have :-). To me it looks to be true but as mentioned I was unable to prove it. A nice challenge!

Comment: @Maestro13 The use of "primitive root" seems very unusual here: why not call it "square root"?

Comment: @ErickWong correct - I updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can easily play the odds by starting with an $n$ which has a lot of modular square roots: if $n$ has $k$ distinct prime factors (of the desired form) then it will have $2^k$ square roots of $-1$.  Since these will, in all likelihood, be distributed randomly in $(1,n)$, then gathering $8$ candidates will give us a very good chance ($1 - 2^{-8} \approx 99.6\%$) of finding one in the second half.  In order to get $8$ multiples of $4$ we should aim for $32$ roots altogether.  So let's pick $k=5$:

$$n = 5 \cdot 13 \cdot 17 \cdot 29 \cdot 37 = 1185665,$$

And we easily verify ([Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%5E2+%3D+-1+mod+1185665)) that $1076028$ is a square root of $-1$ that is a multiple of $4$ that is very far into the second half.

I'm sure that smaller examples exist, but this was almost guaranteed to flush out an example on the first try.

EDIT: Smallest example is $8^2 \equiv -1 \pmod{13}$.  You must have been pretty unlucky to find enough false positives to believe this was true!

Comment: Hm you're absolutely right. I had another restriction on n that was not easy to describe so I asked for a more general assertion. Now need to go back into my cave and try to describe the other restriction on n in an easy way too.

Comment: @Maestro13 Does the restriction on $n$ seem likely to rule out every $n$ with a large number of prime divisors?  If not, then it seems likely the same principle still applies.